# Selenium WebDriver does not navigate to url as soon as headless option is given..

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, headless, selenium

I'm struggling to get **headless** chromium to work in our corporate environment (where we use kerberos authentication).

I can open up pages with a simple script (Nugets Selenium.WebDriver v3.14.0 and Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver v2.41.0 installed).

But *as soon as I specify to run --headless* this doesn't work anymore.

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200", "--ignore-certificate-errors");
using (var browser = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions)) {
  browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://my.corporate.site/home");
}
```

I've seen a thread [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=741872) that "Windows Authentication does not work in headless mode", but this should be fixed from version 65.. 
(I'm running Chrome 68)

I've tried adding "--auth-server-whitelist='my.corporate.site'" but still nothing... (shouldn't be needed in intranet anyway)

Anybody any clues ?

I must add that our environment is very restricted.... (no admin rights)